# Internet doesn't work unless Hotspot Shield is on

Tags: mac, vpn, hotspot-shield

The Internet on my laptop doesn't work unless Hotspot Shield is activated. I use Mac with Google Version 37.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the problem with it. I couldn't surf the Internet without Hotspot Shield, which sucked. But luckily someone in another website told me what to do. If you ever have the same problem. Here's how to fix it: 1. Start >> Control Panel >> Network and Internet >> Network and Sharing Center 2. On the side there is a 'Change Adapter Settings' click on it. 3. Right-Click your Adapter. NOTE: Make sure it is your adapter and not Wi-Fi! In this case my Adapter is Hamachi. So Right-Click >> Status >> Properties 4. Now if you are using Hotspot Shield, you should see 'Hotspot Shield Routing Driver 6' or something along those lines. Disable it by unticking and then Select it. (**MAKE SURE ITS SELECTED! THE WRITING SHOULD BE HIGHLIGHTED WITH BLUE!**) And then press 'Uninstall'. 5. Now reconnect with your Wi-Fi and that should fix the problem. Hopefully :)